# fonts are not loading on MVC.?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

I am building project on MVC it's like my college project. i have uploaded template and made layout in which included all css and scrips. everything seems perfect except fonts.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/frontend/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/frontend/fonts/elegant_font/HTML_CSS/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/frontend/fonts/et-line-font/style.css" type="text/css">
```

inside css i found this is how urls are set should i also set them like links. with ~/contnet like this.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 src: url('/Content/frontend/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot@v=4.1.0');
 src: url('/Content/frontend/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot@#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/Content/frontend/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff@v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('/Content/frontend/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf@v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('/Content/frontend/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg@v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

[Here is location where fonts are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAl0G.png)

[Errors i found with fontawsome are displayed but i have gave proper location where their files are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9lWQ.png)

Comment: find the `@font-face` definitions in your css files and check that the path of the font file is correct and that they exist

Comment: i have edited my post with @font-face css.

Comment: In your browsers network tab, are those fonts being loaded?

Comment: ya try building the path from the root of your project, i.e. `src: url('/Content/...` and make sure the files are really there. And also do what @Amy suggested, you will see in there if it can't find the font files

Comment: It might be worth noting that EOT fonts are usable only with Internet Explorer (unless my info is out-of-date, but I don't think it is).  Since you're including multiple font files, please also indicate which are loading and which are not.

Comment: @Amy i have seen on network that does not show anything about css links with fontawsome i have edited my post with accurate location where fonts are placed still no magic it not getting displayed. getting to annoying with just fonts.

Comment: @kamraan I'm not sure I understand your comment.  If you don't mind, can you share a screenshot of your browsers network tab?

Comment: @Amy none of fonts are seems to be working wherever there are fonts there is nothing getting displayed. specially with font-awsome only if font-awsome get fixed rest are not big deal.

Comment: @kamraan Then it is very likely they aren't going loaded, but I can't diagnose why based on the currently available information.  Is your browser *trying* and *failing* to load the font files?  Or is it not even requesting them?

Comment: @Amy I have updated main post with screenshot links as far as my knowledge i have link them with proper address. since comments are getting more and more. sorry to bother you can you look at issue using team viewer or anything here is kamikamran660@gmail.com my email. sorry if being too personal. i am too curious about this issue,

Comment: @kamraan Okay that was very helpful, thank you.  Notice that your network tab says the font files are returning 404s?  404 means "not found".  Notice on the right side near the top of the Network tab where it says "Request URL"?  That URL is incorrect.

Comment: then what could be the proper url here is complete hierarchy of files

C:\Users\kamik\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AlluringDecors\AlluringDecors\Content\frontend\fonts\font-awesome\fonts

Comment: @Amy i am noticing there is error but how can this be resolve in mvc since normally it not happens with other application it just start work after font-awsome be linked.